# Error installing mysql

Tags: mysql, installation

```
Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-06-26T08:44:42.036600Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-06-26T08:44:42.036600Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-06-26T08:44:42.036600Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-06-26T08:44:42.036600Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 3232, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.11.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database
```

I am having this error in log during the installing of MySQL on the application configuration part.

Comment: Track the bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91476

Comment: Are there any update for answering this question. I face the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Resolved following these steps:
- Rollback installation until initial page and choose remove mysql server
- Uninstall from add/remove programs mysql community installer
- reboot
- install version **mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.22.1** and **select update when it asks**.
- done

Comment: Worked perfectly, I was fighting to install it in my new notebook, thanks for sharing the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to uninstall mysql:

**Step 1.** control panel->programs and then uninstall whole mysql.

**Step 2.** delete folder MySQL from the following path.

1. C:\Program Files\MySQL
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
3. C:\ProgramData\MySQL (your programdata folder is hidden so you have to unhide from c drive->views->options->view ->show hidden files)
   4.C:\Users\hp(your pc name)\AppData\Roaming\MySQL

**Step 3.** windows+r write regedit.exe enter and follow the path and delete mysql Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\

**Step 4.** control panel->administrative tool->services then find mysql copy name then open cmd run as administrative write (sc Delete "mysql name that you copied")enter.

Now you can install MySQL

Answer (score 2):

This is a Bug in the Installer of 8.0.11.
There are changes in the lower_case_table_names variable in the new release. See:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html

Nobody can fix this. If you installing the Server the configfile is write before new. Every time. So if you fix this 0.0 to 0 in my.ini the changes will be overwritten.

Somebody have to report a this bug to MySql.

EDIT:
I have report a bug to oracle:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91539

Comment: I have report a bug to oracle:

Comment: I experienced this issue, and was able to install v. 5.7.22.1 by doing the following: on configuration screen, when you get this error - do not click anything - open the my.ini, replace 0.0 with 1 (if you are on Windows) and, keeping the file open, click "Execute" again. That worked right away for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get rid of this error is by allowing MySQL Installer to update when it prompts to do so at the beginning of the installation. Please note that you will get this error if you didn't allow the installer to update.

Updating `lower_case_table_names = 0` in `my.ini` doesn't fix this because MySql will re-initialize it to 0.0 everytime before running the scripts.

If you didn't allow updates, you will need to uninstall all components of MySql and run the installer again and let it update.

Answer (score 1):

Update the installer for **mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.22.1** file during the installation from the web . I encountered the same problem, after updating the installer it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When I downgrade MySQL from 8.0.11 to 5.7.22, I encountered this error. Spend a lot of time to fix the bug. Finally, I fix this problem by the following steps:

1. uninstall all the related features with MySql( use Control Panel > Programs and Features)
2. go to C: drive, make all hidden files visible(view > hidden items), find ProgramData file
3. delete the MySql file inside hidden ProgramData file manually.
   Make sure all the MySQL files are deleted, reinstall MySQL. It works for me. I successfully installed MySQL 5.7.22 without any problem.

My Guess: This error probably will happen if you are second or third time to install MySql server. It seems like the error happens because the old MySql files are not deleted completely. Usually, we all think that after we uninstall the application, the files are deleted from program files, it is clean, everything was done. However, there still some files hidden from us. We have to delete them by ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

On bug page, last comment states that the latest installer solves this problem.
For me not. The following steps made me a clean install (after get the latest installer):

When it fails on **database initialization** step just cancel it back to the installer's main page where you can see **installed MySQL server** with a reconfigure option.

Now edit the `my.ini` and set the

`"lower_case_table_names=0.0"`

to

```
"lower_case_table_names=0"
```

Click on reconfigure and now it goes over on this problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with 1.4.25 installer and resolved that by doing the following steps [without updating the installer]

1. There is a folder ***MySQL Installer for Windows\Manifest\Templates***
2. In ***Templates*** folder there are few text files which are there to be used as a template during `my.ini` generation. I have commented out the line `lower_case_table_names=`

Now I execute the configuration process using installer and it executes without any error.Also I add the variable later and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

As the bug reported in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91476, upgrade MySQL installer to 1.4.26.0 and reinstall MySQL server would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed mysql server, wizard of installation was stooped at the point initializing database (if necessary) for that I did.

1. remove mysql folder from 'C:\ProgramData' folder. Note: `ProgramData` is hidden. You need to make it visible.
2. Uninstall mysql server if it was in the list of installed programs in control panel.
3. Download mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.13.0 and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all `mySql` from the machine. It can be simply done from the control panel.
This might not solve the problem completely, so remove the `mySql` data from your machine. To do this, you need to delete from `programdata` folder. To access it press `windows + r` buttons and type `%programdata%` then press `Enter`. In there, you should find the `mySql` folder and delete it.

After completing above steps you completely deleted mySql

You can now reinstall it

### OTHER CASE

If this error occurs: `installation missing VCRUNTIME140.dll and MSVCP140.dll missing in machine`, then install it from [this link](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x64.exe), then run it again.

Problem solved!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, tried to change my.ini did't work, so I uninstalled the SQL server, then I google my operating system + Install MySQL videos (In my case "Install MySQL on Windows 8"), then I installed MySQL 5.6.26 then worked.
I think the newer MySQL doesn't support certain old operating system.

Comment: see: [Supported Platforms: MySQL Database](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html)